# Uploading App to Play store, Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier

Tags: android-security

I searched a lot on google and stack overflow but nothing is help full ,i Am getting this error when uploading to playstore , app is working good but still facing this. i checked the code but i never found hostnameverifier in any app file. But i found this word in debugging files can any one help me.

Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface. You can find more information about how resolve the issue in this Google Help Center article.

```
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'


android {
compileSdkVersion 29
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.0.2"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX", onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}


dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
// Androidx Support Library --------------------------------------------------------------------
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

// Google Material Library ---------------------------------------------------------------------
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

// Firebase Library ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.0'

// Squareup API Library ------------------------------------------------------------------------
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.8.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.8.1'

// Volley API Library --------------------------------------------------------------------------
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

// Google Libraries
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'

// Facebook SDK Library ------------------------------------------------------------------------
implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.15.3'

// Add the Firebase SDK for Crashlytics. -------------------------------------------------------
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0'

// One Signal sdk library ----------------------------------------------------------------------
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.15.3'

// Paytm Payment Getway Dependencies -----------------------------------------------------------
implementation('com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.4.4') {
    transitive = true
}

// Paypal Payment Getway Dependencies ----------------------------------------------------------
implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.22.0'
implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.7.1'

// Third Party Dpendencies --------------------------------------------------------------------
implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'           // ripple effect
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'     // image loader
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'         // circle image view
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.3.4'                        // country code picker

annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I have the same issue, after upgrade compileSdkVersion and  targetSdkVersion from 28 t o 29. I can't find any usage of HostnameVerifier in my source code. Other implementation or declaration belong to android sdk.

Comment: @VietNguyenTrong Hi , But Some of your packages from build may indirectly call that function.. I figured that "squareup" package is call that in my case.. Check Debug

Comment: Thank you for your reminder, do you have any idea to resolve them? I'm still stuck on this alert.